# Memory Leaks in Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, memory-leaks

Please tell me how to find out the memory leak in browser and what is the best way to solve the problem. Is there any guideline for writing javascript to avoid memory leak?

And also if you can tell me some problem which you experienced related to memory leak and how did you debug and find out the solution would provide a great understanding to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [this IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/) on Memory leak patterns in JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

For Internet Explorer you can try [sIEve](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626143559/http://home.orange.nl:80/jsrosman/) or the [JavaScript Memory Leak Detector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askie/javascript-memory-leak-detector-for-internet-explorer) from Microsoft (The link to the documentation seems to be broken). In Firefox there is the [Leak Monitor](https://web.archive.org/web/20101204210248/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2490/) Add-on. There is also a list of tools for Firefox [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Performance:Leak_Tools).

**UPDATE:**

There is a new version of the Microsoft memory leak detector at the link below.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/gpde/javascript-memory-leak-detector-v2)